# $f(x)\in D[x]$ is irreducible if and only if $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $D$ be a principal ideal domain and $F$ be its quotient field. Prove that $f(x)\in D[x]$ is irreducible if and only if $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F[x]$.

I only obtained the proof for $D=\mathbb{Z}$ and $F=\mathbb{Q}$. I need to consider the greatest common divisor of a finite set of integers. How to do for all PIDs $D$?

Comment: Use the fact that since $D$ is a PID, $D$ is also a UFD. And all UFD's are integrally closed.

Comment: @TheNumber23 Usually someone who knows what Integrally closed means has already proved this lemma.

Comment: See [this wikipage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29). Scroll down to a paragraph titled "A proof valid over any GCD domain".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look at Ash's book Abstract Algebra: The Basic Graduate Year. He proves the following result:
Let D be a UFD with quotient field F. If f is a nonconstant polynomial with coeffts in D, then f is irreducible over D if and only f is primitive and irreducible over F.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work out a proof, but likely you will be able to use that if $(a)\subset(b)$ then $b$ divides $a$, in the the case of a pid the ideal

$$I=(a_1)+\dots+(a_n)$$

is generated by the analog of the greatest common divisor of $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ . (It is "greatest", in that $I$ is the smallest ideal containing all of the $(a_i)$'s.)

Good Luck.